# How can I make my function faster (the function is looping through a multidimensional array)?

Tags: php, function

My function is extremely slowly! Does anyone know what I did wrong or if it is possible to make it faster?

```
function explodeTree($array, $delimiter = "_", $baseval = false) {
    if(!is_array($array)) return false;
    $splitRE = "/" . preg_quote($delimiter, "/") . "/";
    $returnArr = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
                $parts = preg_split($splitRE, $val['path'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
                $leafPart = array_pop($parts);
                $parentArr = &$returnArr;
                foreach ($parts as $part) {
                    if (!isset($parentArr[$part])) {
                        $parentArr[$part] = array();
                    } elseif (!is_array($parentArr[$part])) {
                        if ($baseval) {
                            $parentArr[$part] = array("__base_val" => $parentArr[$part]);
                        } else {
                            $parentArr[$part] = array();
                        }
                    }
                    $parentArr = &$parentArr[$part];
                }
                if (empty($parentArr[$leafPart])) {
                    $parentArr[$leafPart] = $val;
                } elseif ($baseval && is_array($parentArr[$leafPart])) {
                    $parentArr[$leafPart]["__base_val"] = $val;
                }

    }
    return $returnArr;
}
```

Array before:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["path"]=>
    string(30) "Volumes/folder1/horse/fred"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "fred"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["path"]=>
    string(28) "Volumes/folder1/cat/john"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "john"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["path"]=>
    string(27) "Volumes/folder2/cat/sam"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "sam"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["path"]=>
    string(32) "Volumes/folder2/cat/cat/john"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "john"
  }
}
```

Array after using function:

```
array(1) {
  ["Volumes"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["folder1"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["horse"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["fred"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["path"]=>
          string(30) "Volumes/folder1/horse/fred"
          ["age"]=>
          string(2) "12"
          ["name"]=>
          string(4) "fred"
        }
      }
      ["cat"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["john"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["path"]=>
          string(28) "Volumes/folder1/cat/john"
          ["age"]=>
          string(2) "10"
          ["name"]=>
          string(4) "john"
        }
      }
    }
    ["folder2"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["cat"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["sam"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["path"]=>
          string(27) "Volumes/folder2/cat/sam"
          ["age"]=>
          string(2) "11"
          ["name"]=>
          string(3) "sam"
        }
        ["cat"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["john"]=>
          array(3) {
            ["path"]=>
            string(32) "Volumes/folder2/cat/cat/john"
            ["age"]=>
            string(2) "16"
            ["name"]=>
            string(4) "john"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Providing sample data, explaining what the function does and what "extremely slow" means in terms of seconds is what helps us help you. Regular expressions in every loop is what makes it slow. To make something fast, it must do a small amount of work. That's how we achieve performance.

Comment: A profiler will tell you exactly where the CPU is spending its time in this code. Look into using xdebug for profiling and webcachegrind to display the results.

Comment: How do you call the function? The default value of argument `$delimiter` is `_` but there is no `_` in the input array you posted. And what is the purpose of `$baseval`?

Comment: @Mjh: I posted a sample array. But when I have a lot of content, the array needs some seconds to be created

Comment: @axiac I call it like this: `$my_new_array = explodeTree($array, "/");`

Comment: Please post the expected output when you call it like `explodeTree($array, '/', TRUE);`

Comment: I wonder why the lengths of the `path` strings displayed in your dump are 4 bytes larger than the actual string lengths...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your code produces the same output, no matter if `$baseval` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`. The following code produces the same output, runs fast and gracefully ignores the value of `$baseval` too:

```
function explodeTree(array $array, $delimiter = "_", $baseval = false)
{
    # Build the output here
    $returnArr = array();

    foreach ($array as $item) {
        # Split the path using the delimiter, drop the empty segments
        $pieces = array_filter(explode($delimiter, $item['path']));
        # Turn the path into a nested array
        # Each component of the path is the only key on its level
        # Build it from the leaf up to the root
        $a = array_reduce(
            array_reverse($pieces),        # Start from the leaf
            function (array $carry, $piece) {     # Create parent node...
                return array($piece => $carry);   # ... use the path piece as key
            },
            $item                          # Put the item itself as leaf
        );

        # Combine the new path (nested arrays) into the existing tree
        # array_merge_recursive() takes care of all the levels
        $returnArr = array_merge_recursive($returnArr, $a);
    }

    # That's all
    return $returnArr;
}
```

#### Adding $baseval

I think the purpose of `$baseval` is to put the original properties of an item into a new entry under the key `__base_val` if a subsequent path adds children to a leaf node. For example, if the last entry has `'Volumes/folder2/cat/sam/john'` as `path` then the output of the current code ends with:

```
["folder2"]=>
array(1) {
  ["cat"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["sam"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["path"]=>
      string(23) "Volumes/folder2/cat/sam"
      ["age"]=>
      string(2) "11"
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "sam"
      ["john"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["path"]=>
        string(28) "Volumes/folder2/cat/sam/john"
        ["age"]=>
        string(2) "16"
        ["name"]=>
        string(4) "john"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but the expected output should be (I think):

```
["folder2"]=>
array(1) {
  ["cat"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["sam"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["__base_val"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["path"]=>
        string(23) "Volumes/folder2/cat/sam"
        ["age"]=>
        string(2) "11"
        ["name"]=>
        string(3) "sam"
      }
      ["john"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["path"]=>
        string(28) "Volumes/folder2/cat/sam/john"
        ["age"]=>
        string(2) "16"
        ["name"]=>
        string(4) "john"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above function cannot be modified to produce this output. `array_merge_recursive()` doesn't change the structure of the arrays it is provided to merge; it just combines them.

A complete rethink and rewrite of the function is needed:

```
function explodeTree(array $array, $delimiter = "_", $baseval = false)
{
   # Build the output here
   $returnArr = array();

   foreach ($array as $item) {
      # Split the path using the delimiter, drop the empty segments
      $pieces = array_filter(explode($delimiter, $item['path']));
      # Keep a reference to the current node; start from the root of the tree we build
      $pos = &$returnArr;
      foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        if (! array_key_exists($piece, $pos)) {
            # The path component doesn't exist in the tree; add it
            $pos[$piece] = array();
        } elseif ($baseval && array_key_exists('path', $pos[$piece])) {
            # The component exists, it is a leaf node (has 'path' property) and $baseval is TRUE
            # Save the existing node content
            $val = $pos[$piece];
            # Replace it with a new level; store the old leaf in '__base_val'
            $pos[$piece] = array('__base_val' => $val);
        }
        # Advance to the next level
        $pos = &$pos[$piece];
      }

      # If $baseval is TRUE, make sure we don't mix leaf nodes with inner nodes
      if ($baseval && ! empty($pos)) {
         # The node already has children; put the item in '__base_val'
         $pos['__base_val'] = $item;
      } else {
         # The node was just added; store $item in it
        $pos = array_merge($pos, $item);
      }

      unset($pos);
   }

   return $returnArr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tested your function, but unfortunately the loading time became even longer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into huge amounts of memory reallocations. If you add a `$begin = microtime(true);` at the top of the outer `foreach`, and then `printf('%0.6f', microtime(true) - $begin);` at the end of the loop, do you see the times staying at a roughly stable level or does it get slower as the execution advances?

It looks like you're building a trie. In which case https://github.com/ikcede/PHP-Trie may be of use.